# Traversing a file-system directory structure

Tags: python, directory, scandir, chdir

I am trying to do some work within some files in a directory. The basic structure of what I'm trying to work with is folder -> sub-folders -> files I need to access. `data` holds hundreds of subfolders, I am trying to access each one, find the file within them that ends in `'params'`, and for now just read the contents. My code is below:

```
import os
for sub_folder in os.scandir('data'):
    os.chdir(sub_folder)
    for file in os.scandir(sub_folder):
        print(file.name)
        if(file.name.endswith('params')):
            with open(file.name, 'r') as f:
                data = f.read()
```

I'm getting a `FileNotFoundError`, where it's telling me that the path `'data\\\run.0'` doesn't exist. I have confirmed that `'run.0'` is the first sub folder within `data`, so where I'm confused is how the path doesn't actually exist.

I know the error is happening when I attempt to change directories, so I'm suspecting the way that I am traversing the `data` folder is not a correct way of doing so. I understand that `os.scandir` gives a `DirEntry` object, which is what the variable `sub_folder` will be but is this not a valid input for the change directory function?

Comment: You don't change dir back to the base directory after each loop, so is it looking inside the first folder it found for the second?

Comment: In the second scandir loop, you are not `chdir`'ing into the subfolder, so the current directory is not the one where `file.name` lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.walk`, but I prefer use `glob`: See [How to use Glob() function to find files recursively in Python?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/)

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [link-rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-rot)), answers that provide at least a summary of the solution directly are preferred, with links used to offer additional information.